# Upload large files onto Github, error: remote disconnected

Tags: git, github, git-remote, git-lfs

I am trying to upload files larger than 2GB onto Github. I tried both: using git commands and Github desktop client.

I was trying to add files to github but I could not, I found that it was due to the 2GB limit on file sizes. So I tried using git-lfs (Git Large File Storage (LFS)) to add large files, I followed every step given at https://git-lfs.github.com/, I had no issues other than the last step. Please note that I changed the track commands according to my file type and there was no error. Please find the screenshot of the error that I received using git commands below:

[image]

I also tried using Github desktop client, I am not aware if there is any configuration that would allow me to set the file size limit. After running it using default setting, please find the screenshot of the error below:

[image]

Please help

Comment: According to [Github Help - Managing Large Files - Versioning large files](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/), Git LFS extends the normal 100MB limit to support files up to 2GB in size. I don't see any claim anywhere about supporting files over 2GB on Github.

Comment: you should rethink if you want to save such a big file in a git repository...from what I've seen, most of the times is not a kind of file you want version controlled. Is it a jar? a media file? Something like amazon S3 and a small script to download the file when necessary are usually good solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GitHub LFS:

- does not support such large file (>2GB)
- does not [support different backend](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/193)

You would ned:

- either to use a different Git repo server (like one made to support LFS with S3, with [`meltingice/git-lfs-s3`](https://github.com/meltingice/git-lfs-s3))
- or store your artifact in a binary referential [like Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Git+LFS+Repositories) (which also supports LFS)